# C Programming: Counting word length occurences in a string

Tags: c, string, loops

How would you be able to count word lengths and output their occurrences from a string using `gets()` or `fgets()`? For example, here is code doing so but using `getchar()`below. I think writing it in `gets()` would make it easier to incorporate all of the delimiters in the program rather than having to manually set if statements for each one of those would it not?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
const char delim[] = ", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}\\ / \"";
 #define SIZE 100

 int main(void){
     int length[SIZE] = { 0 };
     int name[SIZE];
     int i = 0, ch, word_len = 0;
     int count = 0;

     printf("enter sentence: ");

     while (1){
        ch = getchar();
          if (isalpha(ch)){
             ++word_len;
         }
         else if (ch == ' ' || ch == '.'){
             if (word_len)
                length[word_len - 1]++;//-1: to 0 origin
             if (ch == '.')
                break;
             word_len = 0;
         }

     }
     printf("Word Length \tCount \n");
     for (i = 0; i<sizeof(length) / sizeof(*length); ++i){
     if (length[i])
            printf(" %d \t\t%d\n", i + 1, length[i]);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `else if (strchr(delim, ch)){` might meet the need.  (replacing `else if (ch == ' ' || ch == '.'){`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your custom delimiter detection function.

```
// globals
const char *delim = " .,;:!?\n\0";
const int n_delim = 9;

int is_delim(int c)
{
    register int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n_delim; i++)
        if (c == delim[i]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

This function will return 1 every time it can match `c` with `delim`. So you can use it like this:

```
fgets(buffer, 200, stdin);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
    if (is_delim(buffer[i])) {
        wl[words++] = length;
        length = 0;
        continue;
    }
    length++;
}
```

I'm assuming you're familiar with the [fgets function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html).

You basically will loop through your buffer, making comparisons with each character. Every loop iteration you check if the current character is a word delimiter, if it is, you save the current `length` and set `length=0` for a new word, and at every iteration you increment the length.

You'll need to come up with a way of either not inserting the zero length values due to double delimiters or just ignore them when you're printing the results.

Comment: Thank you for yor reply enzo! I'm kind of stuck. So length is keeping track of of the word lengths but which variable is keeping count of the type of lengths seen? Is that words?

Comment: Oh wait we require another if statement for that correct?

Comment: @Omar What do you mean by types of lengths? `wl` is an array of `int` keeping the word count and words are _delimited_ by the `delim` array. The `is_delim` function checks if the current character is a delimiter, if it is it returns 1 and we store the `length` variable in the `wl` array. The variable keeping track of word count is `words`, and we increment it every time we add a new word.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to split a string into words, based on some delimiters, and compute their length. The C standard library provides the [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok) function, which does exactly what you need: it splits the given string into multiple tokens.